# How to use imports in Jython, used as standalone jar?

Tags: java, python, jython

I want to run a Java code, which is :

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class PyConv {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.execfile("Test.py");
  }
}
```

And the Test.py file;

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pd.read_csv("Myfile.csv", header=0)
```

But I would get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

So, How would one import the required module, to make the code run?
And also I am using the Jython as a external jar in my java code. Is there any other way which would make my job simpler?

Comment: Does `python Test.py` work?

Comment: have you installed pandas package , if not use - pip install pandas

Comment: It does work with my python interpreter but not working with jython. So, how to install it for jython since 'pip install .... ', does the installation in python libs not Jython.

Comment: I don't think you can use numpy and pandas directly from Jython: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455100/can-i-run-numpy-and-pandas-with-jython

Comment: So, it is still not possible to call a .py file from java, using jython, if it has some external libraries imports. So is there any other method, besides jython I can use to call .py files from java ?