# how to use python file that include python library in java development environment

Tags: java, python, jython

Using jython, I used a Python file in my Java code like below.
package jython_connect;

```
import org.python.core.*;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class jython_test1 {

    private static PythonInterpreter interpreter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.execfile("test.py");
        PyObject str = interpreter.eval("test(7)");
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

And in test.py include python library like numpy.
An import error occurs as shown below.

> ImportError: No module named numpy

I am using Jython 2.7.1, and I ran the below command but it failed.

```
jython -m pip install numy
```

How can I use the Python library in Java?

Comment: NumPy does not work with Jython. See https://scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython-or-c-net, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19455100/407651.

Comment: Can't i use any other Python library?

Comment: You can use most Python libraries in Jython, but not libraries that use C extensions written for CPython (such as NumPy).

Comment: You might want to try JyNI (https://www.jyni.org/) or numjy (https://github.com/Yaqiang/numjy). See also older SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjython%5D+numpy+is%3Aquestion.

Comment: Is there a list of libraries that can't be used with jython?

Comment: I am not aware of such a list.