# How does exec("dir /w"); function work in imageJ?

Tags: python, imagej

How do I use exec() in imageJ, http://fiji.sc/ImageJ_tricks#Execute_external_programs? Can I use the exec() function to launch an external python program with something like:

exec("python", d:\py\program1.py");

Is it possible to return an image array to exec from python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in using additional python libraries with imageJ, exec() can get the job done. Use:

```
exec("python", "d:\\pathtoyour\\pythonprogram.py");
```

Save this using the imageJ script editor as .ijm file. This can then be installed as a plugin to launch your python program from imageJ.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec()` macro function is [hard coded](http://fiji.sc/Functions.java#l4208) to return STDOUT, as outlined in Curtis Rueden's [answer to a similar question on the ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/exec-string-or-strings-tp5004299p5004306.html).

However, you can run [Python (or, for that matter, Jython) scripts](http://fiji.sc/Jython_Scripting#Using_a_jython_script_as_a_plugin) directly from within Fiji via the script editor or by placing them into the `Fiji.app/plugins/` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I ask because I am interested in trying to find a way to use numpy and scipy from ImageJ and thought this could be an option.

Comment: Hm, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097466/using-numpy-and-cpython-with-jython) and this [post on the ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Any-interest-in-reading-numpy-arrays-into-ImageJ-tp3690308p3690309.html) might be of interest for you then.

Comment: Thanks, although I was hoping not to have to rewrite my program to get it to launch in imagej.