# java jython Import error

Tags: java, jython

I use the jython to call python script (use the 3rd lib pykriging) in java. But I get ImportError in java console. I had tried many methods but none works.
My code is like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("python.home","D:\\prog\\Python27");
    props.put("python.console.encoding", "UTF-8");
    props.put("python.security.respectJavaAccessibility", "false"); //don't respect java accessibility, so that we can access protected members on subclasses
    props.put("python.import.site","false");
    Properties preprops = System.getProperties();

    PySystemState.initialize(preprops, props, new String[0]);
    PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
    sys.path.append(new PyString("D:\\prog\\Python27"));
    sys.path.append(new PyString("D:\\prog\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages"));

    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
    interp.execfile("pyt/example.py");

}
```

and the error is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is no way to work it,because 'pykriging' depends on 'numpy',but this is no good way to use numpy in jython.
[Using NumPy and Cpython with Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097466/using-numpy-and-cpython-with-jython)

Comment: Consider not writing your own answer after just 10 minutes; update your question instead.