# Why can't I use numpy library in processing.py?

Tags: python, numpy, processing

My problem is that i can't import numpy into my processing.py project. When I try to import it  i get the error "No module named numpy".  What can I do?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? Make sure numpy is installed for whatever Python you are using (2 or 3).

Comment: have you installed numpy? `pip install numpy`

Comment: Have you installed the package in your virtual envronment(if using one) or your system through pip?

Comment: As @CarlosGonzalez said, go to cmd (Windows) or your Terminal (Linux) and type in ````pip install numpy````

Comment: @Trollsors still dosen't work.

Comment: @HurjuiIonut Do you have pip installed on your computer ? Which version of Python are you using and on what OS ? Did you get any error messages installing numpy (if so what where they) ?

Comment: It's just impossible to help you with this few details. Just check [numpy's getting started](https://www.numpy.org/#getting-started)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Yes i have pip installed. I'M useing Python 3.7.3 on a windows 10, no I didn't get any error when i've installed numpy

Comment: does this command print a version number ? `python -c 'import numpy;print(numpy.__version__)'` Do other pip installed modules work ? Maybe the path where pip installs modules insn't appended to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable ? (I'd also try a system reboot just tick that off the list :) )

Comment: @HurjuiIonut are you using anaconda? check bumpy is installed in your current envir

Comment: @Shijith No, but I had it at a moment in my pc...

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza the good old reboot didnt solve the problem :( that command dindn't outputted a version number indeed

Comment: If the pip install worked with no issues my hunch is Python doesn't know where pip modules are installed. Try to find the `Scripts` folder where pip installed numpy and add that your the `PATH` environment variable and run a new command prompt with the Python interpreter to test. If that didn't work, but numpy is on your system I can think of a hacky test: 1. run a python interpreter from where numpy is installed: `import numpy` should work just in that folder. 2. make a symbolic link (see `mklink` command) from the path where pip installs modules to the default python install `Scripts` ...

Comment: @HurjuiIonut After seeing John Coleman's answer I realise you meant the Processing Python mode, which indeed uses Jython. If it's only rendering you need with using Processing like functions in Python consider trying [pyprocessing](https://github.com/esperanc/pyprocessing) or [p5.py](https://pypi.org/project/p5/) at this point in time.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processing is built on top of the JVM so t[he Python mode of Processing uses Jython](https://py.processing.org/tutorials/python-jython-java/) rather than CPython. Unfortunately, numpy doesn't support Jython. Thus, you are trying to do something which is impossible. From the [SciPy FAQ](https://scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython-or-c-net):

> Q: Does NumpPy/SciPy work with Jython or C#/.Net?
>
> A: No, neither are supported. Jython never worked, because it runs on
>   top of the Java Virtual Machine and has no way to interface with
>   extensions written in C for the standard Python (CPython)
>   interpreter."

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3097466/4996248) discusses some alternatives to numpy which can be used from Jython. The official [Jython FAQ](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq) recommends [JNumeric](http://jnumerical.sourceforge.net/index.html).